# How to know the effect on the predicted value when changing a feature value in random forest?

Tags: python, random-forest

I trained a model that is able to predict the average order volume of an online store. The predictors/features I use include how long the store is open, average price of product, number of brands, etc.

I used random forest regressor in Python and I am happy with the result. However, is there any way that I can know the individual effect of every predictor on the target variable? For example, I predicted that this store will do $50 as the average order volumne. So if I increase the number of brands on the store (one of the predictors), how much will the average order volume increase/decrease?

It's something like the coefficients in linear regression and I know random forest is kind of like a black box but is there any way I can get this without running the whole model again?

I am not able to show the code as it's confidential.

Comment: You may check the importance metric for each predictor, to see which predictor influences the model the most, [see here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/ensemble/plot_forest_importances.html).  Note that the first say 5-7 most important predictors usually dominate most RF models.

Comment: As Tim mentioned you can check the variable importance measures stored in the model. Also, if you want to see how changing some variables changes the predictions you can do that by simply predicting it. Otherwise using something like partial dependence plot can help.